# Mobile Phone Reg expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to find a regular expression for mobile phones that gives me 07550440002 or +4475504400003 up to 20 characters, i.e. I want a regular expression that may + or may not and then a whole number.  I have ^(\+?[0-9])$  but I keep on getting the error message unexpected quantifier.

This happens when I try and run the follwowing code -

```
if (!$(textBox).val().match(RestrictionRegularExpressions.MOBILEPHONE)) {
```

Where RestrictionRegularExpressions.MOBILEPHONE is set the above reg expression

I don't think it likes the \+.

This is using JQuery/Javascript

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `new RegExp(RestrictionRegularExpressions.MOBILEPHONE)`?

Comment: The code is in a function that has a lot of reg expressions, and none of them use new ...  They work fine.

Comment: `.val().match(/^(\+?[0-9])$/)` should work as expected, even though the expression itself is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the given regular expression does not work because the backslash needs to be escaped as well. Using a double backslash should do the trick.

The following regular expression worked for me:

```
^\\+?[0-9]{0,20}$
```

Which I tested using this page on W3Schools web-page: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_regexp_test. It accepts 0 to 20 numbers prefixed by an optional '+' sign.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your  `\+?` works on your language but your regex is false because there can be more than one digit :

```
^(\+?[0-9]+)$
```

Work on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/OGUOqwRMvg).